# Can I use a component library based on Material UI v5 in a Material UI v4 project?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to Material UI in general. I have this React project that uses React v16 and Material UI v4 heavily, and we're currently building a component library that we want to make in Material UI v5 and React v18. I know that React 17+ is required for Material UI v5, but I am wondering if it is possible to update only my React version on my project to React v17 and be able to use my component library with Material UI v5, or do I need to update my core project to use Material UI v5 as well? Not sure if it is even possible, but if it is, are there any risks related to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use a component library based on Material UI v5 in a Material UI v4 project?

Yes, you can follow this guide: https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-data-grid-v4/#using-mui-core-v4-with-v5. It was written for MUI X v5, but it applies to Material UI v5 as well.

> I am wondering if it is possible to update only my React version on my project to React v17 and be able to use my component library with Material UI v5

Both Material UI v4 and v5 are compatible with React v17, e.g. https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.12.4/package.json.